# Debug a very simple code: Cannot delete background image file in a Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

The Form has one Chart and two Buttons. Button1 is to set the Chart1's background image to "1.jpg". Button 2 is trying to delete "1.jpg". An error occurs when clicking B2 after clicking B1, indicating the image file is being hold by another process, hence cannot be deleted.

Any ideas on what happens here?

```
'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Projects\Programs\WindowsApplication2\bin\Release\1.jpg' because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is the vb.net code for the buttons.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).BackImage = "1.jpg"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Dispose()
    Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()

    Try
        File.Delete("1.jpg")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Is the file accessible through Windows file explorer? Meaning, can you delete it or rename the file? It may possible that visual studio is the one holding on to the file from a previous application run.

Comment: to  jwatts1980: the error still appears when I close visual studio and run the executable.

Comment: After a few tests I realised it's the "Chart1.ChartAreas("ca").BackImage = savePath" line which locks the file. Even I reset the BackImage property to empty string, the file seems still locked and become unaccessible.

Comment: Somebody some ideas?

Comment: The `ChartArea` class implements `IDisposable`. I suspect that you are going to have to call `Dispose()` on the `ChartArea` to release the image. It's possible that setting `BackImage = ""` might release it.

Comment: Wierdly, even after disposing the ChartArea object, the image file is still locked, giving the same error.

Comment: Are you still working on this problem?

Comment: Yes I am. The only way I found to detach the file is to dispose the Chart control. However there will be a visible blink when I try to re-plot the chart, for it's large volume of data inside.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why delete the file after setting it to the background?

Comment: Because I use the Chart as a map with some georeferencing. It responses to keyboard events for map maneuver. So everytime the map moves, the background needs geo-referencing, hence creating new file and recycling.

Comment: Too bad the ChartAreas.backimage is a String object, not an Image object.

Comment: Agreed. I am working on a test project. In case it matters, what version of VS and .NET are you using for your project?

Comment: Thank you for the support. VS2013 Express for Windows Desktop.

Comment: .NET 4.5 the latest I guess.

Comment: I believe I have found the solution. And the best part is that you can use a `Bitmap` or `Image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The `Chart` object has a property called `Images`. It contains a collection of `NamedImage` objects. What you should do is create a `NamedImage` for the image you want to add, then release it when you make the change. See the `SetChartImage` method.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private path1 As String = "C:\Users\Developer\Pictures\tmp\1.jpg"
    Private path2 As String = "C:\Users\Developer\Pictures\tmp\2.PNG"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SetChartImage(Chart1.ChartAreas(0), path1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SetChartImage(Chart1.ChartAreas(0), path2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetChartImage(area As ChartArea, imgpath As String)
        'Create the name
        Dim name As String = Path.GetFileName(imgpath)

        'Clear the backimage property
        area.BackImage = ""

        'Release any current images
        For Each ni As NamedImage In Chart1.Images
            ni.Dispose()
        Next
        Chart1.Images.Clear()

       '****DELETE OLD IMAGE HERE****

        'Create the new Image from file, or in any other way that is
        ' needed.
        Chart1.Images.Add( _
            New NamedImage(name, Image.FromFile(imgpath)) _
        )

        'Update the property
        area.BackImage = name
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `BackImage` property can take not only a fully qualified path to the image, but also a key name of an `Image` in the `Chart.Images` collection. After the `Chart1.Images.Clear()` line you should be free to delete the previous image.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I came across Chart.Images yesterday, but no luck for me. I am glad you found the solution.